# Go hijack client connection

Tags: go, go-http

Go language http connection hijacking.

I know how to hijack on server side.
http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Hijacker

But is there way to hijack it on clients side?

Comment: Not really (connections are pooled in the Transport). What is it you actually need to do?

Comment: I have go_client and go_server. Go_server is web server. I wish client to connect go_server to some handler. and after one HTTP request, communicate with it over raw socket. I wish client to hijack http connection. Of course if it is possible. e.g. one of things I could do is HTTP proxy CONNECT instead of GET.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't do this with the default `http.Client`, but `net/http/httputil` has a `ClientConn`, which is a low level http client that directly wraps a `net.Conn`. It's Hijack-able, and operates on standard `http.Request`'s.

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ClientConn

Also, since you control both sides, and you shouldn't see anything too unexpected, it may be easier to simply write the request yourself directly to the TCP connection (or use `Request.Write()` if you want to build the request that way)

Comment: I have not tested `ClientConn` yet. But I believe it is the answer. Thank You